# getting broken images using imgur api even though url works

Tags: php, mysql, image, api, url

Here's my code I'm uploading images using the imgur api and displaying them on the web page by my form. Instead of the actual image being displayed only the broken page icon is shown, and if I copy the broken image into word or notepad then the actual image shows. Obviously the image exists and it's the right path if when I copy it in to word or notepad it shows. Also I'm pretty sure the api works because the imgur url saved in my database works and displays the image. Anything missing or I should change like the way I display the images?

```
if (isset($_POST['post'])) {
    if ($_FILES['postimg']['size'] == 0) {
        $postbody = $_POST['postbody'];
        $loggedInUserId = check::isLoggedIn();
        if (strlen($postbody) > 160 || strlen($postbody) < 1) {
            die('Incorrect length!');
        }

        connect::query('INSERT INTO dry_posts VALUES (null, :postbody, NOW(), 0,:postimg)', array(':postbody' => $postbody));

        // Post::createPost($_POST['postbody']);

    } else {

        $url = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image'; // API endpoints, info: https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image#image-upload
        $client_id = ''; // Get client_id here: https://api.imgur.com/#registerapp

        $fh = fopen($_FILES['postimg']['tmp_name'], 'r');
        $read = fread($fh, $_FILES['postimg']['size']);
        fclose($fh);
        $post = array(
            'image' => base64_encode($read)
        );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Authorization: Client-ID '.$client_id
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $json = curl_exec($ch); // Response, info: https://api.imgur.com/#responses
        curl_close($ch);
        // $image = json_decode($json, true); // Array
        $image = json_decode($json); // Object
        // var_dump($image);
        //$postimg = $image['data']['link']; // Array-style
        $postimg = $image - > data - > link; // Object-style

        connect::query('INSERT INTO dry_posts VALUES (null, \'\', NOW(), 0, :postimg)', array(':postimg' => $postimg));

    }


}
$dbposts = connect::query('SELECT * FROM dry_posts ORDER BY id DESC');
$posts = "";
//here's how I display the images/posts 
foreach($dbposts as $p) {
    if (!connect::query('SELECT post_id FROM post_likes WHERE post_id=:postid', array(':postid' => $p['id']))) {
        $posts. = "<img src='".$p['postimg'].
        "'>".htmlspecialchars($p['body']).
        " <
        form action = 'try.php?postid=".$p['
        id ']."'
        method = 'post' >
            <
            input type = 'submit'
        name = 'like'
        value = 'Like' >
            <
            span > ".$p['likes']."
        likes < /span> <
            /form> <
            hr / > < /br / >
            ";

    } else {
        $posts. = "<img src='".$p['postimg'].
        "'>".htmlspecialchars($p['body']).
        " <
        form action = 'try.php?postid=".$p['
        id ']."'
        method = 'post' >
            <
            input type = 'submit'
        name = 'unlike'
        value = 'Unlike' >
            <
            span > ".$p['likes']."
        likes < /span> <
            /form> <
            hr / > < /br / >
            ";
    }
}
```

and here's the form

```
<form action="try.php" class = "forum" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <textarea name="postbody" rows="4" cols="60" class = "text"></textarea>
         <br />Upload an image:
        <input type="file" name="postimg">
        <input type="submit" name="post" value="Post">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

<div class="posts">
        <?php echo $posts; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you supply an example "Broken" image url?

Comment: weird just now the images started showing yet I didn't change my code I did clear the cache but when I did that it didn't change right away

Answer (score 0):

I think this is called [*anonymous use of the API*](https://apidocs.imgur.com/#authorization-and-oauth), and thus all uploaded images are shared *anonymously*, without being attached to your account.

In order to upload images to your private account, you probably need to get Access Token, and use `Bearer` authentication.